# Binary details option shows french localisation! ios application! apple

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have just uploaded my first application for apple app store approval iOS, I logged on after completeing everything and in the binary details page , in localisation i see ( "English", "French" ), but i do not support french nor have a added any localisation nor mentioned anything in the info.plist.

Also i had added a cutom class in that there is a file CustomClass.strings(French) which i noticed after uploading the binary!

So my first question is : Is it because of this .strings file that I see French in the binary details page?
and second is should I remove this and upload a new binary cause I don't want my app to be rejected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even a single localized file can trigger that behavior - you certainly want to fix the issue and resubmit your app.

Comment: Thanx magma ! i removed that one string file and uploaded again ! It WORKED! now localization doesnt show french!!!